# How to convert an array of list to a single list in node js

Tags: node.js

I have an array in the format

[{"Name":"abc","mark":[10,20,30]},{"Name":"def","mark":[10,20,30]}]

is there a way to convert this array in the following format in node js i tried iterating over and pushing but still not able to get it in following format,

{"abc":[10,20,30],"def":[10,20,30]}

Can any one help me in this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple `forEach` to loop inside the array and create `result` object like:

```js
const input = [{"Name":"abc","mark":[10,20,30]},{"Name":"def","mark":[10,20,30]}];
let result = {};
input.forEach(x => {
  result[x.Name] = x.mark;
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `reduce` to get the desired output

```
const input = [{"Name":"abc","mark":[10,20,30]},{"Name":"def","mark":[10,20,30]}];
const output = input.reduce((acc, curr) => { return {...acc, [curr.Name]: curr.mark}}, {})
```

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)